# How to get distinct rows by id and earliest start date?

Tags: sql, sql-server

how can i group the rows by its id and pick only the one with the earliest start date ordered by start date asc  -- group by and order by?

sample data:

```
id;start_date;description;status;web_enabled;decision
31147020;2014-05-24 00:00:00.000;Description 1;Planning;1; 
31147020;2014-06-14 00:00:00.000;Description 1;Planning;1; 
31147023;2014-04-05 00:00:00.000;Description 2;Planning;1; 
31147023;2014-05-09 00:00:00.000;Description 2;Planning;1; 
31147023;2014-05-10 00:00:00.000;Description 2;Planning;1; 
31147023;2014-05-17 00:00:00.000;Description 2;Planning;1; 
31147101;2013-02-11 00:00:00.000;Description 3;Planning;1; 
31147101;2013-02-13 00:00:00.000;Description 3;Planning;1; 
31147101;2013-02-17 00:00:00.000;Description 3;Planning;1; 
31147101;2013-02-18 00:00:00.000;Description 3;Planning;1; 
31147101;2013-02-20 00:00:00.000;Description 3;Planning;1; 
31147101;2015-02-21 00:00:00.000;Description 3;Registration;1; 
31147108;2014-04-01 00:00:00.000;Description 4;Registration;1; 
31147108;2014-05-16 00:00:00.000;Description 4;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-02-19 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-02-25 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-02-27 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-05-14 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-05-22 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-05-27 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-08-27 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-09-04 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-09-09 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-11-19 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1;
```

desired result:

```
31147020;2014-05-24 00:00:00.000;Description 1;Planning;1; 
31147023;2014-04-05 00:00:00.000;Description 2;Planning;1; 
31147101;2013-02-11 00:00:00.000;Description 3;Planning;1; 
31147108;2014-04-01 00:00:00.000;Description 4;Registration;1; 
31147113;2014-02-19 00:00:00.000;Description 5;Registration;1;
```

Comment: Have a look at [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a ROW_NUMBER to identify the first element. You would partition by the id, then order by start_date so that the first occurrence of each id as determined by oldest start_date would have a `1`, so then in an outer query you can filter to only show where that ROW_NUMBER is 1.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY start_date) AS RowNum
    FROM [SourceTable]
    ) T
WHERE RowNum = 1
```

Comment: @pkosel If the answer helped you, please consider clicking the up arrow next to the answer. If the answer solved your question, please click the check mark under the down arrow. These things help others know your question is solved and which answers have helped, and your reputation will also increase.